# Azure SQL Alter compatibility level Strategy

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a Azure SQL database serverless.

I want to change compatibility level from 120 to 130 :

```
ALTER DATABASE DP300 SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130;
```

What strategy previous to execute `ALTER` should do?

Answer (score 0):

you can change the compatibility level of database using below command

```
  ALTER DATABASE db 
  SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 150;  
  GO
```

[image]

The strategies before change the compatibility level of Azure SQL database are:

1. Export backup files of databases before changing the compatibility level.
2. Have a rollback plan in place in case the update causes any issues.
3. Test the update on non-production environment to confirm there is no issue with existing applications and scripts.
4. check the documentations to know your SQL server version to confirm there is no issue with current configuration.
5. Check the impact of the update on third-parties or applications which are connected to your SQL Server.
6. Monitor the performance of your SQL Server after the update to confirm there are no unexpected issues.

For more clarification you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1178974/azure-sql-alter-compatibility-level-strategy).

Comment: One note. You can't run a backup of Azure SQL Database. You can export to a bacpac, but you can't backup.